# how to move focus in same level in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

can you please tell me how to move focus  in same level when focus in top node.Actually I am using jstree and use it API with jquery.
Firstly I select any node from the tree view after expanding .Then I press button ,It goes to parent node.if it is top node its parent is "#".Now I need if user don't have parent it start moving focus in same level .?

Explain with example;
I expand "c" node.Select "c-a" node.Then press button it goes to "c" node (As expected it goes to it parent).But now when user again press it stop moving it shoulb move to "b" then "a"..

http://jsfiddle.net/fuu94/176/

```
    $('#onelvel').click(function () {
        if($('.jstree-clicked').length){
            if($('.jstree-clicked').next('.jstree-children').length){
                $('.jstree-clicked').click();
            } else {
                $('.jstree-clicked').closest('.jstree-children').prev('.jstree-anchor').click().addClass('jstree-clicked');
            }         
        }
         var selectedItem= $('.jstree-clicked').parent().attr('id');
        alert(selectedItem)
       var parentS= $('#tree').jstree(true).get_parent(selectedItem.toString());

 alert(parentS)      
if(parentS=="#"){
         alert("on b want to go a")
}else{
    alert("going uper node") 
}
    });
```

I am checking api from http://www.jstree.com/api/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting confused with your selectors and how the jsTree reacts to various elements getting clicked.

Have a look at this demo http://jsfiddle.net/XN5JT/1/

Javascript:

```
$('#onelvel').click(function () {
    selected = $('#tree').jstree(true).get_selected();
    parent = $('#tree').jstree(true).get_parent(selected);
    console.log(selected, parent);
    if (parent == '#') {
        $('#' + selected).prev('li').children('.jstree-anchor').click();
    } else {
        $('#' + parent).children('.jstree-anchor').click();
    }
});
```

Comment: can I ask one Question

Comment: can we add a alert when user at "a" node.it show "you will not go above now"